# Assume $A=\{\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2:\lambda\ge 0\}$ Then what $A$ exactly is?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Assume $$A=\{\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2:\lambda\ge 0\}$$

Where $x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb R^2$

Then find a set equivalent to $A$.

I think the set $A$ can be written as $$A=\{\color{blue}{(\lambda a_1+(1-\lambda)b_1,\lambda a_2+(1-\lambda)b_2)}:\lambda\ge 0\}$$

Where $x_1=(a_1,a_2)$ and $x_2=(b_1,b_2)$,moreover the set $A$ also contains the points $x_1,x_2$ themselves,so we can see $A$ as a line passing through $x_1,x_2$, so the equation of that line is $$\frac{a_{2}-b_{2}}{a_{1}-b_{1}}x+\frac{a_{1}b_{2}-a_{2}b_{1}}{a_{1}-b_{1}}$$

But this is valid for $x\le \text{min} (a_1,b_1)$ if the line is increasing and $ x \ge\text{max} (a_1,b_1)  $ if the line is decreasing.

So I could find a set equivalent to the set $A$, but the problem is that I don't have a general equiavalent set for $A$, rather two sets depending on the line being increasing or decreasing.

How to find a general form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the half-line starting from $x_2$ in the direction of $x_1-x_2$. It can be written as $\{x_2+\lambda (x_1-x_2): \lambda \geq 0\}$.

Comment: What line does that specify?

Comment: Draw a line from $x_2$ in the direction of the vector $x_1-x_2$.  A point and  a direction determine  a line, right? @masaheb